# Significance of tasbeeh after prayer

Tags: practical-islam, source-identification

I am getting good in regular prayers (Alhamdulillah), I follow app and it has dua in it for every thing. So after Prayer it has mention of Dua of reciting

1. 33 SubhanAllah
2. 33 Alhamdulillah
3. 34 allah ho akbar

Now it doesn’t give reason or any benefit of it and one might need to know reason and benefit and perhaps where it is mentioned to do such.

Is there any reference of doing it after every namaz? I have included them after every prayer before or after dua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on many sahih narrations like [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/186) in Sahih Muslim:

> There are certain ejaculations, the repeaters of which or the performers of which after every prescribed prayer will never be caused disappointment:" Glory be to Allah" thirty-three times." Praise be to Allah" thirty-three times, and" Allah is most Great" thirty-four times.

However the more known practice is saying:

Subhan Allah 33 times.
Alhamdulillah 33 times.
Allahu akbar 33 times.
And completing 100 by saying La ilaha illa Allah (there's no other deity but Allah) as most narrations quote the 99 first words (see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/235) and [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/504940)) . And that one linked above saying one should say Allahu akbar 34 times is only a single narration. 
All these words are dhikr you praise Allah by subhan Allah, you thank Him by Alhamdulillah and you witness His greatness by Allahu akbar. Note that you may say them as in three sequences of different dhikr (in the order above without mixing praising Allah and thanking him or witnessing His greatness) or as 33 sequences of three different dhikr (subhan Allah, Alhamdulillah, Allah akbar 33 times).

Comment: Thanks, ur wisdom and knowledge always impress me and I wish to have same too. I didn't understand the last bit of that Bukari Sharif which is"Say "Subhana l-lah", "Al hamdu li l-lah" and "Allahu Akbar" thirty three times each after every (compulsory) prayer." We differed and some of us said that we should say, _"Subhan-al-lah" thirty three times and "Al hamdu li l-lah" thirty three times and "Allahu Akbar" thirty four times. I went to the Prophet (ﷺ) who said, "Say, "Subhan-al-lah" and "Al hamdu li l-lah" and "Allahu Akbar" all together [??], thirty three times."_

Comment: @Nofel that's what I actually proposed as an option to say the three dhikrs consequently 33 times (the last sentence in my answer).